# xcodebuild no such module 'SwiftyJSON' while build in xcode works

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swifty-json

In my project, I'm using CocoaPods and podfile looks like this:

```
def shared_pods
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.1.4'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.3.0'
  pod 'PromiseKit', '~> 4.4'
end

target 'myop' do
    shared_pods
end
```

build via xcode **works fine**, but if I try to build via command line ( xcodebuild tool), I get the following error:

```
error: no such module 'SwiftyJSON'
import SwiftyJSON
```

I have tried reinstalling SwiftyJSON and upgrading it to a new version.
Also tried to manually add SwiftyJSON.framework to ***Build Phases*** -> ***Link Binary With Libraries to link***.

Common cause of this error is running project instead of workspace, but I'm not doing this mistake, this is the command I'm running:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ./myproject.xcworkspace -scheme myproject -configuration test -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/boris/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-12-13/myproject\ 2017-12-13\ 13.08.14.xcarchive archive
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get a good answer here?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral check the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, it was a silly mistake.
Unlike from OSX file system, xcode seems to be case sensitive.
Configuration ***test*** does not exist, but ***Test*** does (First letter is uppercase).

So the command should go like this:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Test ...
```

or if you're using fastlane:

```
fastlane gym --configuration Test ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error in a project. I had been setting the `BUILD_DIR` and `BUILD_ROOT` environment variables as part of my call to `xcodebuild`. Removing these variables made the build work.

Answer (score -1):

Do a `pod install` before you do the xcodebuild on the command line.

Comment: I didn't get why it should help, if autor mentioned that he did reinstall of SwiftyJSON ?